# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean

Tags: php, html, parsing

I wanted to parse some informations out of a website but the above error is coming

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on
>   boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Parser\parse_berufsfotografen.php:7 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Parser\parse_berufsfotografen.php on line 7

My Code is:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = "http://www.berufsfotografen.com/reportagefotograf-eventfotograf";
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thank you!!

Comment: This means `file_get_html()` got an error, so it returned `false`.

Comment: Simple HTML DOM has a size limit. How big is the page you're scraping?

Comment: The limit is 600,000 bytes. You can edit the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` constant in the script to increase it.

Comment: Might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983). It's a fundamental of PHP